rerunfilecheck: where does check on toc come from
I observe the following in my log:
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `manualLMP.idx' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun LaTeX/makeindex to get index right.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `manualLMP.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

The first is clearly seen in the code of rerunfilecheck,
whereas the second is not.
On the other hand,
the message clearly indicates that the warning comes from rerunfilececk.
Who can help me to understand?
Also rerunfilecheck has no setting to activate checking particular files like out.

Without minimal working example I would guess, you are using hyperref, which uses reruncheckfile in several backend drivers. See, e.g., hpdftex.def. If you need more information or a real answer, please show a MWE, so we can reproduce the warning messages.

@cabohah you are right.. I should have known from ending .out.
Although I was not very specific, you answered my question.

rerunfilecheck provides a macro to activate checking arbitrary output files such as \jobname.out called \RerunFileCheck and documented on pages 2-3 of the package's documentation.
\RerunFileCheck{<file>}{<action>}{<warning>}

For example,
$ grep '\\RerunFileCheck' $(dirname $( kpsewhich hyperref.sty))/*
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/backref.sty:  \RerunFileCheck{\jobname.brf}{%
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvipdfm.def:  \RerunFileCheck{\jobname.out}{%
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def:  \RerunFileCheck{\jobname.out}{%
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def:  \RerunFileCheck{\jobname.out}{%
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hvtex.def:  \RerunFileCheck{\jobname.out}{%
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def:  \RerunFileCheck{\jobname.out}{%
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def:  \RerunFileCheck{\jobname.out}{%

shows several results for \jobname.out as cabohah indicated.
Edit
Note that \RerunFileCheck is only needed when a check is required for an arbitrary output file such as \jobname.out. Most cases are dealt with by rerunfilecheck's builtin support for standard output files such as \jobname.toc, \jobname.lof, \jobname.lot etc. (option starttoc for toc-like listings), \jobname.aux (options mainaux and/or partaux) and index or glossary files (options index and glossary).
Option starttoc supports any toc-like listing which invokes \@starttoc, so it is not necessary for the code to limit supported files to any predefined list of extensions. If you rewrite the code used to generate a listing of this kind such that it omits \@starttoc, this would obviously break, but standard approaches all use this, so support for additional listings works out-of-the-box otherwise.
Regarding index, makeidx is not required to make an index. (And makeidx still requires you to run makeindex before recompiling the document.) You might want to use the LaTeX kernel's unmodified setup, but you also might want to use a different package such as imakeidx (which can run the index programme automatically) or a class which includes builtin support for indexing. You also might wish to use a different programme to sort the index, since makeindex has some frustrating limitations (e.g. for languages other than English, handling of spaces etc.). So, yes, there's good reason to support a more general indexing mechanism rather than requiring use of one specific modification of the standard setup.

you are right, I should have read more carefully.
By the way, in my texlife distribution I found only a single invocation of \RerunFileCheck besided hyperref: hypdoc... ok rerunfilecheck itself.

@user2609605 you only need it for non-standard files and creating such files is very expensive since the number of possible writes is limited to 16 by default. (you can get around this, but it is easier if you don't have to.) even packages which write additional files may only need checks for standard files, so it's not so surprising if this particular interface is used fairly rarely.

@ cfr You mean I dont need it for toc, lol, lot, lof?

@user2609605 no. you can use the starttoc option, for example. similarly, there are ready-made options for checking aux files, index and glossary. hyperref needs \RerunFileCheck because .out is peculiar to hyperref and not already accounted for by rerunfilecheck. most checks will only need to hook into the code rerunfilecheck has already setup.

@user2609605 note that starttoc is not just for the toc. it will also do the job for other toc-like files such as lof, lot etc.

@ cfr I researched more carefully now... true: starttoc is not only for toc.
I tried with lof, lot, lol (list of listings).
Also I went through the code of rerunfilecheck.
I cannot figure out how rerunfilecheck hooks into.
Where do the concrete endings go into?
Also the documentation offers an open list as you do also.
Is there a complete list of endings starttoc operates on? All floats?
How is rerunfilecheck applied to the concrete ending as lol? I would have expected some according code in package listings.

@ cfr Is there a reason to offer support for idx files not inside the according package makeidx?
THe only difference I see is, that not only latex must be rerun, but in addition the tool makeindex must be invoked in advance.

@user2609605 please see edit.
